# Error in sending and receiving the packets

Tags: networking, wireshark, libpcap, winpcap

I am writing an application to inject packets to the adapter using the winpcap API "pcap_sendpacket" and I am also running a separate thread to get all the packets received by the adapter from the network which forwards the packets to my application for processing when it receives any packet from the network.

Problem is, I am seeing the injected packets in the "pcap_loop" callback which I am sending using the "pcap_sendpacket". This is causing an issue of sending the injected packets again back to the application.

What I should do, If I don't want to receive the injected packets?

How to differentiate between the injected packets and the packets received by the network adapter from the network?